# lambda в массиве

Tags: python, функции, lambda

**Есть код:**

```
a = [x for x in range(10)]  #[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

list(map(lambda j: j * j, a))
print(a) #[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Он, к сожалению не работает, но почему? Вроде бы все правильно

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы результат никуда не сохранили

```
a = list(map(lambda j: j * j, a))
```